# Installing Xcape (question involving the "make" command)

Tags: command-line, compiling, executable, xcape

I executed the minimal building directions of [xcape](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xcape):

```
$ sudo apt-get install git gcc make pkg-config libx11-dev libxtst-dev libxi-dev
$ mkdir xcape
$ cd xcape
$ git clone https://github.com/alols/xcape.git .
$ make
```

But when I press `xcape` it says `xcape: command not found`.  It errors even when I'm in the `xcape` folder with a program that seems to be called `xcape` inside it.  Why is this?

Comment: Have you logged out, and back in again to update your `$PATH`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried  `./xcape` ? You have to execute it this way, because the location is probably not defined in the $PATH variable.